# what's the deal with Cookie.setMaxAge(Integer.MAX_VALUE)?

Tags: java, servlets, cookies, websphere

[setMaxAge](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html#setMaxAge%28int%29) is supposed to control the maximum age of a cookie, so if my intention is to literally set the maximum age possible the logical thing would be doing:

```
cookie.setMaxAge(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

However this results in no `Expires` in cookie HTTP header at all, I'm testing it on a WebSphere 7. Setting it to something like 1 year measured in seconds works fine.

Why is that happening?

PS
Have just tested on Tomcat7 - Integer.MAX_VALUE results in `Max-Age=2147483647; Expires=Wed, 06-Mar-2080 21:30:32 GMT`, so it must be something wrong with WebSphere.

Comment: http://www.javaworld.com/community/node/3673

Comment: Yes, that's my article. But there's nothing about Integer.MAX_VALUE in it.

Comment: Quick test, worked as you were expecting on WebSphere 6.1. I don't have a WebSphere 7 environment on which to test. Did you test other expiration values?

Comment: I just ran a quick test on WAS 7 and found the same thing that you did. Cookies with other max ages are created as expected, but not for cookies with the max age set to Integer.MAX_VALUE or other large values. (I tried some arbitrary large values - 1500000000 worked but 2000000000 did not.)

Comment: So this must be a bug in WAS 7. Anyone wants to report to IBM? will be glad to accept an answer which says APAR is being produced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is described in http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM34869.
Cause is a kind of millenium problem: WAS7 writes cookies date as YY, WAS6 as YYYY